# Which Jersey version runs in Jenkins 2.107.1?

Tags: java, jenkins, jax-rs, groovy-grape

We are running a Jenkins on Ubuntu.

When we try to use a Java library in a Pipeline that uses REST calls, we run into problems. [UriBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html) is apparently used in a old version: The method `toTemplate` is missing and caused a MethodNotFound. This is strange because the Java library depends transitively on

```
<groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
<version>2.0.1</version>
```

which contains the new version of UriBuilder. We used Grape and correctly copied the library with all transitive dependencies to Jenkins. Outside Jenkins, the library works fine.

My guess: Jenkins runs on a version of Jetty which provides an old version of UriBuilder which somehow "wins" against the new version of UriBuilder from javax.ws.rs-api 2.0.1?

Can anybody shed light on this?

Comment: I haven't been able to find a UriBuilder anywhere in the jenkins 2.107.1 ubuntu distribution

Comment: Deactivation of the Jira Plugin did the trick. See also https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44378. I wonder: Is it possible to separate the class loading of the plugins and my pipeline? Can I use a separate JVM?